# Math Grammar on a Poster

Tags: matrices

I am trying to figure what is the correct phrase in the bolden phrase. The article, where I am doing my research on, states: Let S be the set of all 2x2 matrices with equal positive integral entries. Let T be the set of all 2x2 matrices with equal integral entries. My professors are getting frustrated due to the circle effect that I am making the same error over many times. So what is the correcting words that fixed? Is it "having" or other words.

Beginning:

Different algebraic systems raise many questions. For instance, can the elements in a given system always be factored into primes? If so, what theorems can help factoring the elements? Are the factors unique? The poster will discuss the answers to these questions through examples and theorems for a class of 2×2 matrices **with equal integers entries**. 
Let S be the set of all 2×2 matrices **with equal positive integers entries**.

Conclusion: 
The elements of the set T can always be factored; however, most of the elements in the set T are not uniquely factorable. There are theorems that can assist in determining the factorization of elements of T. Future investigation might include studying whether there are similar theorems for each class of n×n matrices **with equal integers entries**.

Thanks, 
cba

Comment: Change "integers" to "integral" in the bolded phrases.

Comment: You may also want to replace "might" with "may."

Comment: With "equal integer entries", so a $2$ by $2$ matrix with $4$ entries all equal to $3$, say?